# How to implement popup in Windows Phone

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, windows-phone-8.1

I'm implementing a templated control, which should work as virtual keyboard button - when you hold it, it displays a popup with additional options to choose.

I've implemented the popup more less in the following way:

```
<Grid>
    <Border>Content</Border>
    <Grid x:Name="gPopup" Visibility="Collapsed">
         <StackPanel x:Name="spSubItems" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I show the popup by changing visibility to visible and setting negative margins for top and bottom. However, when I do that, and when the popup is actually larger than the control, the control is being resized to match its size - despite fact, that it is not inside:
[image] [image]

How can I implement the popup, such that it won't expand the container it's on? And such that the container will still match size of its contents?

---

**Edit**: In response to comments and answers

I'm not sure if I'm understood correctly. Here's an image with explanation:

[image]

I'd like to keep the original container's size the same after showing the popup. I'm unsure how WrapPanel or DockPanel could help me with that.

Comment: Try using DockPanel instead of StackPanel.

Comment: @xmashallax Windows Phone does not have `DockPanel`. And this is not `StackPanel`, which causes trouble, but main `Grid`.

Comment: My bad...it's part of the Silverlight Toolkit that I use in every project so I wasn't aware that it's not part of the WP core.

Comment: Did you try setting alignment to `Center` on Border with content? Together with Padding this sould prevent it from stretching and keep some free space on the sides.

Comment: Install-Package WPToolkit and add your XAML reference the following:  xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit". Maybe benefits to your business (You can use toolkit:WrapPanel,StackPanel or DockPanel)

Comment: You can download from this web site : http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/1-toolkit/1639c502-4896-4167-a77a-0ad46ff11223      I hope that helps

Comment: How about overriding MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride in your templated control? Not sure if it'll work, but you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simply to use Popup instead of positioned Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Sample- Create a grid

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <!-- Setting a Rectangle having transparent background which set the
   Visibility of popup -->
   <Rectangle Name="popupRect" Fill="#80000000" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
   <!—Here in the above Code we are just filling the rectangle With the transparent BackGround -->
   <!—Creating A Border -->
   <Border Name="popupBorder" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
   <!-- Creating A grid Inside the Border and Rectangle -->
</Grid>
```

Create event for which popup should appear(for both cancel and appear)-

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   popupRect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
   popupBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
private void popupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   popupRect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   popupBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

It will work, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Like spook says, put your gPopup Grid in a Popup element and show it by opening the popup. This won't affect the main visual tree.

The reason the embedded grid embiggens the border is that the outer grid has to expand to hold pGrid and the border expands to fill the outer grid.

Comment: Ahem. **I** am Spook. I mean, OP :)

Comment: You're referring to me both in first and in third person in the same sentence. That's kinda weird :)

Comment: English is weird :) I referred to you in third person ("spook") to acknowledge that you (spook, 2nd person singular) had already said this part. The overall comment to which "your" (2nd person plural) applied was addressed to people writing Xaml apps in general.